# Android Media Player back button null pointer crash

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

I have the rest of my app running amazingly well until it comes to the back button being pressed to stop and exit the program.  I didn't know if its this part of the line of code or where but here is the DDMS logcat and below is the back button coding.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
05-03 18:32:35.597: W/KeyCharacterMap(475): No keyboard for id 0
05-03 18:32:35.597: W/KeyCharacterMap(475): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-03 18:32:35.667: D/AndroidRuntime(475): Shutting down VM
05-03 18:32:35.677: W/dalvikvm(475): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.mrj05hua.skylanders.SkylandersSoundboardActivity.onBackPressed(SkylandersSoundboardActivity.java:344)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1888)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2068)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 18:32:35.736: E/AndroidRuntime(475):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 18:32:39.327: I/Process(475): Sending signal. PID: 475 SIG: 9
05-03 18:36:59.016: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 873 objects / 61256 bytes in 96ms
05-03 18:36:59.316: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 276 objects / 13632 bytes in 70ms
05-03 18:36:59.626: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 139 objects / 7040 bytes in 82ms
05-03 18:36:59.936: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 88 objects / 4552 bytes in 78ms
05-03 18:37:00.416: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 96 objects / 5184 bytes in 92ms
05-03 18:37:00.826: D/dalvikvm(484): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 101 objects / 5520 bytes in 90ms
05-03 18:37:35.257: W/KeyCharacterMap(484): No keyboard for id 0
05-03 18:37:35.257: W/KeyCharacterMap(484): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-03 18:37:35.336: D/AndroidRuntime(484): Shutting down VM
05-03 18:37:35.349: W/dalvikvm(484): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at com.mrj05hua.skylanders.SkylandersSoundboardActivity.onBackPressed(SkylandersSoundboardActivity.java:344)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:1888)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2068)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-03 18:37:35.427: E/AndroidRuntime(484):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

--

```
       @Override 
  public void onBackPressed(){
     //Handles back button to close MediaPlayer
        if (player.isPlaying()) {
            super.finish();
        }
        else if (player.isPlaying())
              player.stop();
          player.release();
          super.finish();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one you have a redundant if statement

```
if (player.isPlaying()) 
...
else if (player.isPlaying())
...
```

You are checking the same thing in both of these statements

Next, the reason you are getting the null pointer is because `player` likely is null when you are trying to access it

Make sure you check to see if player is null before accessing it

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed(){
  if (player != null){
      if(player.isPlaying())
          player.stop();

      player.release();
  }

  //there is no reason to call super.finish(); here
  //call super.onBackPressed(); and it will finish that activity for you
  super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I adjusted to this code and I am still getting the same error when the player is doing nothing and the user presses the back button it force closes. I know the != means not null but it wont accept player == null as the else if command.  any ideas on that part of this issue.

Comment: Nevermind your code works great, I found my error where I forgot and placed a player.release(); in the on destroy, after clearing that out it works amazingly well.  Thank you for solving that month long riddle for me.